# Custom Listview with Radiobutton, selected several .. Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom Listview like the following image. But to select the first radiobutton, also selects the one after the scroll ends, according eh read that is by recycling views using android. I tried several solutions but I have not been successful .. If anyone has been the same would like to see if I can help .. Here is the code for my Apadapter you take a look .. Cheers ... !!

**Link Image >** http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2014/11/10/141110041729113463.jpg

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.pregunta = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.texto_pregunta);
        viewHolder.rdo1 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.pregunta.setText((position + 1) + ".- " + desc.get(position));
    holder.rdo1.setText(minimo.get(position));
    return rowView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView pregunta;
    public RadioButton rdo1;
    public RadioButton rdo2;
    public RadioButton rdo3;
}
```

Comment: Remove 'if (rowView == null) {' and check.

Comment: wooooooooooooooooowww,  Something as simple solved my problem, but not only that also save the state of a radiobutton in arrayList

Comment: but this is not the best way to do, if your list grows it may throw ANR.

Comment: then I need to do? what is the best way

Comment: Romadja suggestion is the way how it should be done.

Comment: have a look at my solution with checkbox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470089/why-did-the-listview-repeated-every-6th-item/41900575#41900575

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who responded. reading the responses I received, I found the solution.

I leave my adapter to use it if they have the same problem as me ...

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> minimo;
private final ArrayList<String> maximo;

private ArrayList<Boolean> status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> min, ArrayList<String> max) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, min);
    this.context = context;
    this.minimo = min;
    this.maximo = max;

    //initialize all with false
    for (int i = 0; i < minimo.size(); i++) {
        status.add(false);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.pregunta = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.texto_pregunta);
    viewHolder.rdo1 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.pregunta.setText("Some Text Answer");
    holder.rdo1.setText(minimo.get(position));
    holder.rdo1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            //change status when clicked
            status.set(position, isChecked);

            //verified status all radiobuttons
            for (int i = 0; i < status.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("Log", "" + status.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
    holder.rdo1.setChecked(status.get(position));
    return rowView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView pregunta;
    public RadioButton rdo1;
    public RadioButton rdo2;
    public RadioButton rdo3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can store the checked value in your model. I see that you use lists to store some data, so you can also create one more list with checked, and then use it in `getView` method:

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> checked;

holder.rdo1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            checked.set(position, isChecked);
        }
});
holder.rdo1.setChecked(checked.get(position));
```

Comment: Implement your code. And I do not select the 2 radiobuttons, but now when I scroll and return back to the first question. the radiobutton is no longer selected. Actually I had never encountered this problem, now I realize I know nothing.