# ANDROID - ListView items don't show properly

Tags: android, listview

I made an app and I' am showing images in `ListView`. I have the height of the list item small and after a few insertions in the 9th item of the list is showing the first one I inserted. Why is that happening?

I think the problem isn't in the databse because when I clicked the item and open up the details screen is the proper image in it.

I can't figure what is the problem! Any ideas?

**My Adapter** is :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Clothes> items;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context _context, List<Clothes> _items){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        this.items = _items;
        this.context = _context;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Clothes clothes = items.get(position);

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cloth_item, null);


            TextView category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
            TextView size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_size);
            TextView style = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_style);
            TextView brand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand);
            TextView state = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_state);
            ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            category.setText(clothes.getCategory());
            size.setText(clothes.getSize());
            style.setText(clothes.getStyle());
            brand.setText(clothes.getBrand());
            state.setText(clothes.getState());
            photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(clothes.getPhotograph()));
        }
        return view;

    }    
}
```

And **my list** is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categorized_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use view holder to bind view in list

Comment: View this question ..it will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470089/why-did-the-listview-repeated-every-6th-item

Comment: Thank you everyone! Yes just the holder made the miracle!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="YourClass"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_notification">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewNotification" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a file called list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/notificationMain"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rippleNotification"
        ripple:rv_color="@color/rippelColor"
        ripple:rv_rippleDuration="200"
        ripple:rv_type="rectangle">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.bonafyd.foruser.forImageLoading.ImageViewRounded
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/notiAvatar"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Notification"
                        android:textColor="#343434"
                        android:id="@+id/tvNotification" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate" />
                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Aadapter

```
class NotificationAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<NotificationValues> notificationArrayList;
    public NotificationAdapter(ArrayList<NotificationValues> list)
    {
        notificationArrayList = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notificationArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return notificationArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflaterPostPanel = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflaterPostPanel.inflate(R.layout.notification_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        TextView tvNotification = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotification);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        RippleView rippleNotification = (RippleView) row.findViewById(R.id.rippleNotification);
        ImageViewRounded notiAvatar = (ImageViewRounded) row.findViewById(R.id.notiAvatar);

        final NotificationValues notificationValues = notificationArrayList.get(i);
        tvNotification.setText(notificationValues.notifText);
        tvDate.setText(dbManager.getTimeStampNew(notificationValues.notifDate));

        Picasso.with(context).load(notificationValues.avatar).resize(90, 90).centerCrop().into(notiAvatar);

        final SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("User", 0);
        rippleNotification.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
                }
        });


        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Clothes clothes = items.get(position);
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cloth_item, null);
    }
    TextView category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
    TextView size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_size);
    TextView style = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_style);
    TextView brand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand);
    TextView state = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_state);
    ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    category.setText(clothes.getCategory());
    size.setText(clothes.getSize());
    style.setText(clothes.getStyle());
    brand.setText(clothes.getBrand());
    state.setText(clothes.getState());
    photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(clothes.getPhotograph()));
    return view;
}
```