# firebase database or my listview is duplicating data after first few items

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase database and glide to access images stored in firebase storage. but when i run the code it seems to duplicate the items after the first 6. here is my database ref

```
ref = db.getReference().child("LOGOS");
```

Which in my database looks like this

```
{
  "70s": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "80s": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "90s": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "COMMERCIAL": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "DANCE": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "HIPHOP": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "MASHUP": "My FirebaseStorage https web address",
  "NEWS": "My FirebaseStorage https web address"
}
```

then here is my coding

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Genre_Adapter adapter;
        imageUrl.clear();
        
        for (DataSnapshot snapa : snapshot.getChildren()) {
      

            String logo = snapa.getValue(String.class);

            imageUrl.add(logo);

// I've added a Log here to see that the data returns the right values and it 
// does, but when loaded in to the list view it repeats.

            String key = snapa.getKey();

            Log.e("KEYS", key);
```

these are the values returned in my log

```
this is what is returned when i log.e the string key

2022-08-15 11:47:08.958 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: 70S
2022-08-15 11:47:08.959 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: 80S
2022-08-15 11:47:08.959 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: 90S
2022-08-15 11:47:08.959 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: COM
2022-08-15 11:47:08.959 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: DANCE
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: DRUM & BASS
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: HIPHOP
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: MASHUP
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: NEWS
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: TRANCE
2022-08-15 11:47:08.960 19751-19751/com.p9p.radioify E/KEYS: UNITEDKINGDOM
```

this is where i convert to an array for my adapter class

```
            imageurl = imageUrl.toArray(new String[imageUrl.size()]);
            adapter = new Genre_Adapter(getContext(), imageurl);
        }#

  adapter = new Genre_Adapter(getContext(), imageurl);
            mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            
            mlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    genre_list_item gli = new genre_list_item();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("Genre", btntitle.get(position));
                    Log.i("genre_title", btntitle.get(position));
                    gli.setArguments(bundle);
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame1, gli, "genre_list_item")
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();


                }
```

this is my adapter class

```
public Genre_Adapter(Context context,String[]logo){
    this. context = context;
    this.logo = logo;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return logo.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return logo[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View row;

    if (convertView == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.genre, parent, false);
        imageView = row.findViewById(R.id.image);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }
    Glide.with(context).load(logo[position]).into(imageView);

    return (row);
}
```

****EDIT**
I have tried these answers today. None of which have worked.

[Why did the ListView repeated every 6th item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470089/why-did-the-listview-repeated-every-6th-item)

Also this is an image of my app to show what is happening
[image]

Comment: Is your database constantly changing?

Comment: @AlexMamo only as im adding new items

Comment: So isn't the data duplicating **only** when you're adding items?

Comment: @AlexMamo no its permeant ive even tried moving to just a child called logs so its on its own n it still does it

Comment: Have you tried changing `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`? Dies it work this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo no i haven't but ill try that now n get back to you

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247281/discussion-between-markharrop-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: So, did that change solve the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo could it be something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470089/why-did-the-listview-repeated-every-6th-item

Comment: It's possible, you can try that solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this i such an easy fix i could kick my self for not getting it
the imageview in my adapter was being initialised in the wrong place.
replacing

```
 if (convertView == null) {
    row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.genre, parent, false);
    imageView = row.findViewById(R.id.image);
} else {
    row = convertView;
}
Glide.with(context).load(logo[position]).into(imageView);

return (row);
}
```

with

```
if (convertView == null) {

        row = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.genre, null);

    } else {
       row = convertView;
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Glide.with(context).load(logo[position]).into(imageView);
    return row;
}
```

corrected the issue lol